# multi type record consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a kafka topic, where each record will look like this:

```
{
  messageType: "A"
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to have spring-kafka listener, for each possible type, rather than every listener receiving all type of messages and ignoring unwanted messages?

Answer (score 1):

You can have one `@KafkaListener` but with different method for each payload type. Annotate them with `@KafkaHandler` and Spring will select method for each event based on payload type.

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaHandler.html

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible, but that's not how Kafka consumers actually work. There will still be one consumer reading that one topic before deciding to reroute the function call to a specific handler. Therefore, there's no clear benefit of

```
@KafkaListener processA(Message value)
@KafkaListener processB(Message value)
```

Over

```
@KafkaListener process(Message value) {
  switch (value.getMessageType()) {
    case "A":
      processA(value);
      break;
    case "B":
      processB(value);
      break;
  }
```

... other than code style. But then you're coupling your logic to Spring framework, and may make it more difficult to test or refactor